# Remove text appearing between two characters - multiple instances - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In Microsoft Excel file, I have a text in rows that appears like this:

```
1. Rc8 {[%emt 0:00:05]} Rxc8 {[%emt 0:00:01]} 2. Rxc8 {[%emt 0:00:01]} Qxc8 {} 3. Qe7#  1-0
```

I need to remove any text appearing within the flower brackets `{` and `}`, including the brackets themselves.

In the above example, there are three instances of such flower brackets. But some rows might have more than that.

I tried `=MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("}",A2)-1),FIND("{",A2)+1,LEN(A2))`

This outputs to: `{[%emt 0:00:05]}`. As you see this is the very first instance of text between those flower brackets.

And if we use this to within SUBSTITUTE like this: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("}",A2)),FIND("{",A2),LEN(A2)),"")`

I get an output like this:

`1. Rc8  Rxc8 {[%emt 0:00:01]} 2. Rxc8 {[%emt 0:00:01]} Qxc8 {} 3. Qe7#  1-0`

If you have noticed, only one instance is removed. How do I make it work for all instances? thanks.

Comment: Are you open to using vba to write a custom function to do this? Alternatively, could you repeat your function as many times as necessary in your sheet to remove all strings?

Comment: There are several thousands of rows. I think custom function might be better. I have used the function by @dirk-reichel and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that easy without VBA, but there is still a way.

Either (as suggested by yu_ominae) just use a formula like this and auto-fill it:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("}",A2)),FIND("{",A2),LEN(A2)),""),A2)
```

Another way would be iterative calculations (go to options -> formulas -> check the "enable iterative calculations" button)
To do it now in one cell, you need 1 helper-cell (for my example we will use `C1`) and the use a formula like this in B2 and auto-fill down:

```
=IF($C$1,A2,IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(B2,MID(LEFT(B2,FIND("}",B2)),FIND("{",B2),LEN(B2)),""),B2))
```

Put "1" in C1 and all formulas in B:B will show the values of A:A. Now go to C1 and hit the del-key several times (you will see the "{}"-parts disappearing) till all looks like you want it.

**EDIT**: To do it via VBA but without regex you can simply put this into a module:

```
Public Function DELBRC(ByVal str As String) As String
  While InStr(str, "{") > 0 And InStr(str, "}") > InStr(str, "{")
    str = Left(str, InStr(str, "{") - 1) & Mid(str, InStr(str, "}") + 1)
  Wend
  DELBRC = Trim(str)
End Function
```

and then in the worksheet directly use:

```
=DELBRC(A2)
```

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Answer (score 5):

Highlight everything
Go to replace
enter {*} in text to replace
leave replace with blank

This should replace all flower brackets and anything in between them

Answer (score 1):

Try a user defined function. In VBA create a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5. Then add this code in a module.

```
Function RemoveTags(ByVal Value As String) As String
    Dim rx As New RegExp
    rx.Global = True
    rx.Pattern = " ?{.*?}"
    RemoveTags = Trim(rx.Replace(Value, ""))
End Function
```

On the worksheet in the cell enter: `=RemoveTags(A1)` or whatever the address is where you want to remove text.

If you want to test it in VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = "Rc8 {[%emt 0:00:05]} Rxc8 {[%emt 0:00:01]}"
    Debug.Print RemoveTags(a)
End Sub
```

Outputs "Rc8 Rxc8"