# How to get mutiple substrings in Microsoft Excel Cell

Tags: excel, regex, vba, powerquery

I'm trying get from a cell just the value of the 'id' tag separated by ';'.

The data is as follows:

Cell:

```
A1: {"id":1145585,"label":"1145585: Project Z"}

A2: {"id":1150322,"label":"1150322: Project Waka 1"}|{"id":1150365,"label":"1150365: Project Waka 2"}

A3: {"id":1149240,"label":"1149240: Analysis of Technical Options"}|{"id":1149258,"label":"1149258: Check and Report"}

A4: {"id":1148925,"label":"1148925: Change Management Review"}|{"id":1148920,"label":"1148920: Follow-Up Meetings"}|{"id":1148923,"label":"1148923: Launch Date Definition"}
```

I have tried to use `left`, `mid` and `find` functions, however the number of 'IDs' can vary from 1 to 1000. I'm also trying to avoid using vba, but it seems to be the only option. So any solution is great!

The result should be:

Cell:

```
A1: 1145585

A2: 1150322;1150365

A3: 1149240;1149258

A4: 1148925;1148920;1148923
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835136/remove-text-appearing-between-two-characters-multiple-instances-excel

Comment: Google how to use [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) in VBA there are many tutorials. Try something on your own before you ask us to do the work for you. Use a pattern like this for example [`"id":([0-9]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/PDTwsn/2) to get all the IDs

Comment: Alternatively do a RegEx substitution with this: https://regex101.com/r/is7xLx/1 You can paste your data in the "Test String" and get your IDs in the "Substitution".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a task for `#powerquery`. Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is availeble in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

The steps are:

1. Load the source data to power query editor which should look like the following:

[image: Step1]

2. Use **Index Column** function under the `Add Column` tab to add an Index column;

[image: Step2]

3. Use **Split Column** function under the `Transform` tab to split the column by custom delimiter `"id":` and put the results into **Rows** as shown below:

[image: Step3]

4. Use **Extract** function under the `Transform` tab to extract the first **7** characters of the column;

[image: Step4]

5. Change the `Data Type` to **Whole Number**, remove Errors, and then change the `Data Type` back to `Text`;

[image: Step5]

6. Use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to group `Column1` by `Index` as set out below. Don't panic if the result is in `error` as it is expected.

[image: Step6]

7. Go back to last step and replace the original formula in the `formula bar` with the following one as `Text.Combine` is not a built-in function:

`= Table.Group(#"Changed Type3", {"Index"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Column1],";"), type text}})`

[image: Step7]

8. **Close & Load** the output to a new worksheet (by default), and you should have the following:

[image: Step8]

Here are the Power Query M codes behind the scene. Most of the steps are performed using built-in functions except the last step of manually replacing the formula with the correct one. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("""id"":", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Extracted First Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1", {{"Column1", each Text.Start(_, 7), type text}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted First Characters",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Changed Type2", {"Column1"}),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Errors",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type3", {"Index"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([Column1],";"), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Nicely done. Although you can remove the extraneous rows with a filter. Nice edit of the SUM function.  I've converted the Table to a List with `Table.Column` and then combined it.  Your method is simpler for numeric data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I actually tried to use FILTERXML but only able to find the first number string. I guess this function is not good for finding multiple strings or I need to try harder :)

Comment: Multiple number strings can be returned, but an issue with `FILTERXML` is that it will convert numeric data to "real" numbers, thereby dropping any leading zero's or other formatting. I tend to avoid it when the numeric format is not necessarily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @TerryW comment, here is a solution using the `FILTERXML` function available in Excel 2013+.  But it also requires `TEXTJOIN` which did not appear until later versions of Excel 2016 (and office 365)

It relies on the fact that the id string is always followed by a comma.

A disadvantage is that `FILTERXML` will return the numeric id's as numeric values. So leading zero's will be dropped. If there are always a fixed number of digits in the id and leading zero's need to be present, this can be mitigated by using the `TEXT` function.

We construct an xml by dividing both on `id` and on `comma`

We then use an xpath to return the node which **follows** the node that contains `id`

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""id"":",",id,"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[text()='id']/following-sibling::*[1]"))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

**Source**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Great work! Now I see how to return multiple strings using **FILTERXML**, the key is to use **SUBSTITUTE** to put comma `,` or a symbol in front and after the target string and replace it with `</s><s>` and then use `following-sibling` to return the strings.