# Remove Text Within Cell Starting with String and Ending with Character

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling trying to figure how to remove text that begins with some text and ends with a character:

I have a cell in Excel that could have a string:

[#1-Some text][#4-Some more text][#7-Some additional text]

OR

[#4-Some more text][#7-Some additional text]

I need to remove [#4-Some more text], but keep the remaining text

Visual:
[image]

I want to use VBA to remove "[#4-Some More Text]", but that string could be different, the string will

- always start with a "[#"
- then a number (which could vary in a different search, but I can get programmatically)
- then a "-" (dash)
- then some varying text
- then end with "]"

I am creating the first part "[#4-" (because the number could change) programmatically and the snippet always end in a square bracket, the text in between could be different

I've tried tweaking multiple other posts:
[Remove text appearing between two characters - multiple instances - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835136/remove-text-appearing-between-two-characters-multiple-instances-excel)
[Remove text that is between two specific characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352746/remove-text-that-is-between-two-specific-characters-of-a-string)
but can't seem to get it right.

Can someone please help or direct me to a similar situation?

Thank you!

Comment: [#4-Some more text] is not always the same but will always start with square bracket, the # symbol, a number and a dash... then some text... then end with a square bracket

Comment: They all start with a [number which can change- , and contain #'s right ? And all end with ][#..  and so on. ? Without a better clearer excel example it's hard to see what's going on , can you edit it post a little ? .  But counting the number of ['s or ][ in your cells could give you a key/clue.

Comment: just edited, David, hopefully helps clarify

Comment: Len(a1)-len(substitute(a1,"][","")) gives me value of 4 for 3 snippets.

Comment: Not really clear on your requirements but would the Split function be useful for you? `Splt(YourText,"[#")(X)` where `X` is the element number. To use it properly you would put it into a variant array like `MyArr = Splt(YourText,"[#")` Then you can use the boundary of the array to find the last one like `msgbox MyArr(ubound(MyArr))` which will show the last element. Changing ubound to lbound will show the first.

Comment: Wow, turns out it was a combination of both splitting the text and getting the remaining length, thanks to both of you to leading me in the right direction. I was so caught up trying to make those other solutions work, lost sight of the simplicity. I'll update my answer when I've cleaned up my code - THANKS!!

Comment: Interesting that I spelled Split wrong twice. Glad you managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regext should help you out

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String

    s = "[#1-Some text][#4-some more text][#7-Some additional text]"

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "\[#4-[a-zA-Z ]+\]"
        .ignorecase = True
        Debug.Print .Replace(s, vbNullString)
   End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Got it to work with combination Split and Len (and Right$), but this worked too, thanks!