# Removing text with certain pattern in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove part of text in a cell with pattern such as [cid:image003.gif@01D863CC.CAE51sd0] & [https://xxxx=0].

It may appear several times in each cell randomly in different position.

I read some material ([Remove Text Within Cell Starting with String and Ending with Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291580/remove-text-within-cell-starting-with-string-and-ending-with-character)); but I have no clue how to handle the code with looping and line by line within a cell

I prepared 2 samples.

**Sample A:**
Hi xxx,
This is Ken
[cid:image003.gif@01D863CC.CAE51sd0]
[https://xxxx=0]

[cid:imagedddd0]

**Expected:**
Hi xxx,
This is Ken

**Sample B:**
[cid:image003.gif@01D863CC.CAE51sd0]
[https://xxxx=0]

Hi xxx,
This is Ken

[cid:imagedddd0]

**Expected:**
Hi xxx,
This is Ken

Comment: Why not try Text to Columns with a `[` delimiter? It should at least more quickly break them up, especially if it can occur ore than once per cell.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something to any cell which has certain character, "[" and "]". What you want to do to that kind of cell, you want to remove all those "[", "]" and the value in between those two certain characters.

Example data in the active sheet:
[image]

The cell with that kind of data in yellow is scattered around to whatever cells in the active sheet.

if your data is similar with image above and the image below is your expected result after running the sub:
[image]

then the sub is something like this :

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
Dim pos1 As Long: Dim pos2 As Long

Do
    Set c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("[", LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Do
                pos1 = InStr(c.Value, "["): If pos1 = 0 Then Exit Do
                pos2 = InStr(c.Value, "]")
                c.Replace What:=Mid(c.Value, pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 1), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
            Loop
        End If
Loop Until c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

There are two loops in the sub.
Loop-A is to find any cell of the active sheet which has "[" character and have it as c variable
This loop-A will stop when it doesn't find a cell which has "[" char.

Loop-B is to do something whenever there is "[" in the found cell.
This loop-B will stop if in the found cell there is no more "[" char.
What the sub do in this loop-B is to find the position of "[" as pos1 variable and find the position of "]" as pos2 variable. Then it replace the "[", the "]"
and whatever text in between those two char in the found cell (the c variable) value with nothing ("").

---

After seeing the sample data, I think it's better to do it in MS Words app. So I search the internet on how to do VBA in MS Words app. Not exactly sure if it's a correct syntax, but it seems the code below (MS Word VBA module) work as expected.

```
Sub test()
Dim pos1 As Long: Dim pos2 As Long
Dim txt As String: Dim slice As String: Dim rpl As String

Do
    pos1 = InStr(ActiveDocument.Content, "[")
    If pos1 = 0 Then Exit Do
    pos2 = InStr(ActiveDocument.Content, "]")
    txt = Mid(ActiveDocument.Content, pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 1)

        If Len(txt) > 250 Then
            slice = Left(txt, 250): rpl = "["
        Else
            slice = txt: rpl = ""
        End If

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:=slice, ReplaceWith:=rpl, _
        Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Loop

End Sub
```

The process of the sub is similar with the one in Excel app. The difference is, this sub check if the char is more then 250 in the text to be removed (the txt variable) then it will slice it the first 250 char into slice variable, and have "[" as the replacement into rpl variable.

If the txt variable is not more than 250 char, then the slice variable value is the same with the txt variable value, while the rpl variable value then it's just directly nothing ---> "".

**WARNING:**
In my computer, **the sub takes almost 2 minutes to finish the job in MS Words app** with the data coming from column A of your Excel sheet sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried the code. I get a "Run-Time Error Type Mismatch". Do you mind share your file to me? I have uploaded my one to the link below. Thank you.
https://cantirecorp-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ken_chan_cantire_com1/ES5ln0E3Y49BnZcZz2ujCOIBaJd7KkLjMvXiXiRpDVmgkQ?e=gU4aIb

Comment: @KenChan, sorry I just found out that the find/replace cannot exceed than 250 char. And in your data, the some of the text to be replaced is more than 250 char. Anyway, I think you'd better put/copy/have your data in column A (since I see there is nothing in the rest of the column) in MS Words application. You can see better text in Words and you can still remove the unwanted text. Please have a look my test sub for the Words app.